# Best way to link output of C++ code into python

Tags: python, c++, stdout

Suppose I have the following files:

```
input.txt
foo.cpp
foo (executable)
bar.py
```

```
(input.txt)
qwert
as
zxcvqwer
tyu
...
```

I want to use my foo executable to run a program that has input the `input.txt` file and output some response to it, for example, the length of each string (this is not a real example):

```
./foo input.txt

stdout
4
2
8
3
...
```

I want that result to go into my python program, I have thought on two ways of doing that:

- Running the executable to write the answer to a `output.txt` file and then read this file in python;
- Running the executable and getting the stdout directly (using something like `subprocess`).

My question is: Is there any difference in performance in doing any of those? Is there a better way to do that?

My real problem is because I want to run a machine learning algorithm that I wrote in C++ because of performance and I want to get the result to Python because it is better to deal with tabular data

(I don't know if this is the right stack exchange to ask this but if there is a better one please let me know)

Comment: That sounds like exactly the use case `subprocess` was made for. And regarding performance (not that I would even bring that into the question) any disk I/O you can skip will obviously be faster, so avoid the extra file writing.

Comment: Great! thanks for the explanation. Maybe a silly question but the stdout is stored into memory or it is written in the storage like a regular file? @CoryKramer